# Understanding pricing of QuickSight with respect to source

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I’d like to understand how the pricing for the AWS service QuickSight works. From the [QuickSight pricing webpage](https://aws.amazon.com/quicksight/pricing/) I can see two editions, Standard and Entreprise, and the plans Authors or Readers.

When creating a new dataset on QuickSight I can specify different sources, among them I have S3, using a manifest file, and Athena, connecting to a table. I’ve seen on StackOverflow [technical pros and cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47354233/why-athena-for-quicksight-if-quicksight-direct-query-s3) between these two sources and [help as for setting up QuickSight permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59412925/should-quicksight-need-access-to-the-s3-bucket-athena-is-querying).

Now I’m not sure if and how the source, here S3 and Athena for my interest, is going to impact on the price for the plan that was selected. My understanding is that QuickSight will either read the data from the S3 bucket (which I believe always occurs with a cost) or query them using Athena (which also has a cost from scanning the data).

My questions would be:

**Does the source affect the price? 

If yes, how does it work out?**

I’d be interested in reading experience on this or any official documentation which I was not able to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question after contacting AWS Support.

The pricing of QuickSight, as given [here](https://aws.amazon.com/quicksight/pricing/), is not affected by the choice of the source to upload the data. There is however an additional cost to access this data, but it is billed separately (i.e. not as part of the QuickSight product) depending on the source. The pricing of sourcing from S3 will follow this [reference](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/), the pricing of sourcing from Athena that [one](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/pricing/).

Comment: Does quicksight try to reingest s3 files its already imported in the past or does it know only to import new s3 files over the entire bucket? Just dont want to get stung by API costs.

Comment: @mRyan did you get an answer to your question?